# Centring Authors in IEEEconf

Tags: ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am using [IEEEconf](https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html) to write my paper. The author section is like this:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\title{paper title}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

 hello!
 \end{document}
```

The template says that all the affiliations must be separate. So, for four authors I get this:
[image]

Which doesn't seem right since the fourths author should be in the center (I guess) and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I still could not compile your code

Comment: @Cragfelt I have added the link for the template. I don't know what should I add to the code so everyone can run it.

Comment: read *IEEEtran_HOWTO*. there is clearly stated that authors in the form, as you wish is, is possible up to 3 authors. for more you should use an alternate long format (without use of `\and`).  however, in it  authors are listed below each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458208/190770

The construction of the author block is contained within an `@IEEEauthorhalign` environment that has `\hfills` on either end. This allows the author block to be centred in general. For multiple authors, each `\and` (in conference mode) closes the `@IEEEauthorhalign` environment, issues an `\hfill` and then opens `@IEEEauthorhalign` again.

In order to introduce a line break and have the author content still be aligned properly, I've defined a new command called `\linebreakand`. It does what every `\and` does, excepts introduces a `\par` and a new `\hfill` for the new line start.
[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\title{A title}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
  \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
  \hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}
\makeatother

\author{
  \IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
  \linebreakand % <------------- \and with a line-break
  \IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```