# IEEEtran document class — how to align five authors properly

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, ieeetran, author

How do I align author names such that the first three authors appear in 3 column format and the last two in two column?

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The construction of the author block is contained within an `@IEEEauthorhalign` environment that has `\hfill`s on either end. This allows the author block to be centred in general. For multiple authors, each `\and` (in `conference` mode) closes the `@IEEEauthorhalign` environment, issues an `\hfill` and then opens `@IEEEauthorhalign` again.

In order to introduce a line break and have the author content still be aligned properly, I've defined a new command called `\linebreakand`. It does what every `\and` does, excepts introduces a `\par` and a new `\hfill` for the new line start.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\title{A title}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
  \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
  \hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}
\makeatother

\author{
  \IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
  \linebreakand % <------------- \and with a line-break
  \IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
  \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Works perfectly. Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: Works in general, but it get an error `LaTeX Error: \begin{@IEEEauthorhalign} on input line XX ended by \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}.` (but looks fine)

Comment: @KevinWittek I ran into the same problem, because I only used the `linebreakand`-command and not the leading and trailing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands. Adding them to be exactly like in this example solved the error.

Comment: works beautifully!