# How to Line Up Author Names in IEEE Template

Tags: templates, ieee-style, author

i have to use the IEEE Latex [Template](https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html) for the Conference Paper. I downloaded it and the Authors do not line up correctly. The names are displayed to each other.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{Paper Title*\\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
should not be used}
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{6\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address}
}

\maketitle

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
component, formatting, style, styling, insert
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]
Any Ideas how to fix this Problem ? (Because this simply looks stupid.)

Answer (score 4):

There's a (remarkably) similar question here, answered by @Werner.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458208/174282

He creates a new command \linebreakand, which is place after your third author to make the proper alignment. Read his answer linked above to learn more. I've just pasted it quickly into your example.

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    \begin{document}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
      \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
      \hfill\mbox{}\par
      \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
    }
    \makeatother



    \title{Paper Title*\\
    {\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
    should not be used}
    \thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
    }

    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
    \linebreakand % <------------- \and with a line-break
    \IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
    \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{6\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
    }

    \maketitle

    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
    component, formatting, style, styling, insert
    \end{IEEEkeywords}

    \section{Introduction}
    \end{document}
```

And here's the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the question is a duplicate, it is better to mark it as such than to copy answers from the duplicate. (You will be able to leave comments pointing to the duplicate once you have some more reputation.)