# Authors names in separate columns with alignment and email with underscore

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ieeetran, author

I just come across an issue, I've document template `\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}` and I entered coauthors name like that

```
\author{Name$^*$,Name$^\dag$, Name$^*$, Name$^*$,Name$^\dag$\\
 $^*$University,City, Country\\
 $^\dag$,City, Country\\
 $^\dag$ University,City, Country\\
 Correspondence: email}
```

However, I got instruction that authors names should be in separate columns. To address this I used the following code

```
\author{
    Name \\
    {\textit{ University}}\\
    City, Country \\
   email address
  \and
   Name\\
{\textit{ University}}\\
   City, Country\\
    email address
    \and
    Name\\
    {\textit{University}}\\
     City, Country\\
    email address
    \and  {\hspace{1.5cm} 
   Name}\\
    { \hspace{1.2cm} \textit{ University}}\\ {\hspace{1.2cm}
    City, Country}\\
    {\hspace{2cm} email address}
     \and
    {\hspace{-4.5cm} Name}\\
    {\hspace{-4.5cm} \textit{University}}\\
    {\hspace{-4.5cm}City, Country\\} \\
    {email address}
    
}
```

, This code somehow gives me separate columns, however, the story does not end here, my last coauthor email includes underscore "_" which e.g ABC_Gmail.kr, I used everything to write the email e.g., `\email`, `\href`, `$\_$`, `$_$` but it is not working, and if it does not work it makes code out of use means column are into one another, my question is simple,
how to fix email errors with the same code (2nd one). Thanks

Comment: Regarding the underscore: Did you already try `\_` as in `ABC\_Gmail.kr`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IEEEtran document class — how to align five authors properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458204/ieeetran-document-class-how-to-align-five-authors-properly)