Spacing between authors when there's only one author on a line in IEEE Template
While an answer was posted in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458208/174282, it fails to take into account the scenario when there's only one author on a line. Thus,
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\title{A title}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
  \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
  \hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}
\makeatother

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email.address@banana.com}
        \linebreakand % <------------- \and with a line-break
    \IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email address}
        \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
    \textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
    City, Country \\
    email.address@banana.com}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}

Relevant screenshot of result:

How do I increase the spacing between authors in this case? Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you!
